# Starting a new thread within synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

May be this is a basic question, but would like to get a confirmation from this forum.

I have the below code logic:

```
public Object method1() {
 synchronized(this) {
  method2();
  method3();
  method4();
}
```

`method4()` is a time consuming operation and I don't have to wait for its completion. So I wrote an spring method interceptor which will intercept the `method4` invocation and execute it in a separate thread. Now my question is will method1 return immediately after the method 4 execution starts?

Below is the Interceptor code:

```
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
    Future<Object> future = executorService.submit(new AsyncCallable(
            methodInvocation));
    Object retVal = null;
    try {
        retVal = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception while running the method Async", e);
        throw e;
    }
    return retVal;
} //AsyncCallable implements Callable interface
```

Comment: You are starting it in another thread but aren't you immediately waiting for it?

Comment: This is easy enough that you can run it and see what happens.  Try it!

Comment: Ok. I tried by making the method4() run in infinite loop and it times out after 10 seconds [my timeout limit]. So method1() definitely waits for the thread to complete its execution. I don't get what is wrong in the code. Is there anyway to make the thread async?

Comment: @Ganesh sure, if you don't wait on the `Future`.

Comment: @Ganesh, you stated: "method1() definitely waits for the thread to complete its execution".  No, it doesn't.  It waited for `method4` to return, which it did after the timeout.  The thread is looping infinitely (as you stated), and continues to run.

Comment: @RichardSitze Yes, you are right. I phrased it wrongly.

Comment: @Ganesh So what is it that the code isn't doing, that you think it should be doing?

Comment: @RichardSitze I was waiting on the future (10 seconds) but I wanted the method1 to return immediately irrespective of what happens to method4. Now I removed the future.get call and it returns immediately. It was a complete misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Stated: `method4()` is a time consuming operation and I don't have to wait for its completion.

Ok, threading is a good solution for that.  HOWEVER, by that very statement you've suggested that what you want is for immediate return, which would immediately exit the synchronized block.

So, first question: Is that what you really WANT to occur?  Maybe not... maybe.  If it's safe to process `method4` outside the sychronized block, then move it out of said block.  If it's not safe, then maybe what you want to do is intercept (and thread) `method1`?

---

Meanwhile, back to `method4`: As coded, your intercept steps in, creates the future, and then waits for up to 10 seconds for the future to complete.  The intercept returns after that (completion or timeout).  Control passes back to method1, exits block/sychronized loop.

Comment: If I don't have the sync block, would method1() return immediately?

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I don't wait on the future, method1 returns immediately.

Comment: @Ganesh your question suggests strongly that you may not be clear on the meaning/purpose of the synchronize keyword.  You might go read up on it.